# Open dialog ignores my selection

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, hardware

On Windows 7 Pro SP1 I use an application written in C++ using Qt. Everything worked fine till now, but today, when I tried to open a file that should be processed by this application, nothing opens and the dialog just disappears. I don't know about any action that would cause this. I also tried the version of the program on Ubuntu and the same problem occurs. So I installed Virtual XP on my Win7 host, installed there the program and surprisingly - again the same problem. So where to find the reason? HDD? I tried to defragment, but with no success.

Comment: Do you have the source code to the application?  Debug it.

Comment: I don't have the source. But I've been using it ca 1 year without any problem.

Comment: Is there a space in the directory path or filename where there never was before?  Some programs don't handle spaces in paths well.

Comment: neither spaces nor problematic characters - only letters and digits